# Android Firebase User ID mapping issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I had integrated Firebase analytics in Android few months back. 
Initially I was setting the user_id wrongly, by using the following code :

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("userId", "<value_of_type_1_for_user_id>");
```

As a result my user_id column in bigquery was null. Hence on my next release, I corrected it and used the following method :

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserId("<value_of_type_2_for_user_id>");
```

This created a problem as all those users who had installed/used the app between those two release dates have an extra user property key named "userId". And this has some wrong values of user_id.

Now, another strange thing that has happened is that there are many new users who are onboarding the platform now with the latest version of APK. A small percent of these users still have the malicious key of "userId" under user_properties.

I need help in understanding the following : 
- Understanding the reason behind why new users (a random small group of them) are still being affected by this wrong mapping ?
- How to clean up the user property field of old users by removing this property key for all users.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user property "userId" to null/empty and the user property will be removed from the future events. User property will stick with events until you explicitly remove it.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like this might clean up the malicious data. Will try and update here.